# "THREE.GLTFLoader: No DRACOLoader instance provided" despite providing one

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to load a GLB model in Three.js in order to render it in a WebXR augmented reality scene. However, the model doesn't show up and I am receiving the error

> THREE.GLTFLoader: No DRACOLoader instance provided

in the console, despite explicitely providing one:

```
import { GLTFLoader } from "gltf-loader";
import { DRACOLoader } from "draco-loader";

// ...
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

load(model, onModelLoad) {
    loader.load(model, onModelLoad, undefined, (loadingError) => {
        if (loadingError.message.includes('THREE.GLTFLoader: No DRACOLoader instance provided')) {
            tryLoadingModelWithDRACO(model, onModelLoad);
        } else {
            logger.error(loadingError);
        }
    });
}

tryLoadingModelWithDRACO(model, onModelLoad) {
    logger.info("Trying to load model with DRACO");
    try {
        const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
        dracoLoader.setDecoderPath("/static/draco/");
        dracoLoader.setDecoderConfig({ type: "js" });
        const loader = new GLTFLoader();
        loader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);
        loader.load(model, onModelLoad); 
    } catch (dracoLoadingError) {
        logger.error(dracoLoadingError);
    }
}
```

I downloaded the draco_decoder.js file and it is correctly put in the folder specified in setDecoderPath() (i am also not receiving a 404, so the file is located correctly). However, i still receive this error when trying to load the GLB model. Why? I am obviously providing a draco loader instance in case GLTF loading didn't work.